# How can I call a method in a base Frame Renderer from the iOS Custom renderer?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this code:

```
public partial class PhrasesFrameRenderer : Frame
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    private int answeredPhraseCount;
    private int correctAns;

    public PhrasesFrameRenderer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        App.PhrasesFrameRenderer = this;

        public void abc()
        {

            ....
        };
```

and the custom Renderer

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(PhrasesFrameRenderer), typeof(PhrasesFrameCustomRenderer))]
namespace Japanese.iOS
{
    public class PhrasesFrameCustomRenderer : FrameRenderer
    {
        UISwipeGestureRecognizer leftSwipeGestureRecognizer;
        UISwipeGestureRecognizer rightSwipeGestureRecognizer;
        PhrasesFrameRenderer frame;
        bool rightSwipeEnabled = false;
```

Can someone explain to me how I can call the ABC function in the Phrases FrameRenderer from the custom Renderer code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your CustomRenderer the `Element` property is basically the view you declared in the PCL Xamarin Forms class in your case `PhrasesFrameRenderer`

You just need to cast this property to the class and you will have access to all the public methods and properties.

```
var frame = (PhrasesFrameRenderer)Element;
frame.abc();
```

or

```
var frame = Element as PhrasesFrameRenderer;

if(frame != null)
    frame.abc();
```

This should work.

**One note**: I would not call the Custom views as Renderer as this can create confusions with its actual renderer. Your custom frame could just be named `PhrasesFrame`

Comment: So are you suggesting PhrasesFrameRenderer be renamed to PhrasesFrame? How about PhrasesFrameCustomRenderer, do you think that would be better named as PhrasesFrameRenderer?

Comment: Yes, for the view `PhrasesFrame` appending the word "Renderer" as I previously said could be confusing cause that's not a renderer but just a view. In the case of the `PhrasesFrameCustomRenderer` just calling it `PhrasesFrameRenderer` is fine, at least that's the convention most use.

Answer (score 1):

So the 'ExportRenderer' flag basically tells the native project that if it is trying to display that type of control, override where necessary anything used in the native code (I.E. the overriden methods in your class 'PhrasesFrameCustomRenderer').

What this means is that your custom renderer doesn't technically derive from your custom frame, it derives from a special xamarin forms class, in this case the class called 'FrameRenderer'. So it doesn't have access to any of the methods in your derived control in your forms project ('PhrasesFrameRenderer').

So the solution to your answer depends entirely on what you're trying to achieve.

If you simply want to invoke that method at a certain time, then you could look into subscribing to the messagingcenter, if you want access to variables/data that the method may create, then that could be done by a generic static dictionary for setting and getting objects.

**EDIT** MessagingCenter Example:

```
public partial class PhrasesFrameRenderer : Frame
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    private int answeredPhraseCount;
    private int correctAns;

    public PhrasesFrameRenderer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        App.PhrasesFrameRenderer = this;
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<App>(App, "invokeABC", abc);
    }

    public void abc(App obj)
    {


    };
}
```

and in your custom renderer you need the following wherever you want to invoke that method:

```
MessagingCenter.Send((App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "invokeABC");
```

This all assumes that you do not need to pass any data between the two classes.

**EDIT** Static pointer

Taking a closer look at your code you place a pointer to your custom frame in a variable in your App class. so in theory you could call

```
App.PhrasesFrameRenderer.abc();
```